# How to do the following SCSS in stylus

Tags: css, sass, stylus

I have the following SASS function which i am struggling to convert to stylus. The online converters seem to struggle with it also.

```
@function multiple-box-shadow ($n)
    $value: '#{random(2000)}px #{random(2000)}px white'
    @for $i from 2 through $n
        $value: '#{$value} , #{random(2000)}px #{random(2000)}px white'

    @return unquote($value)
```

Answer (score 0):

The following works.

```
random(min,max)
    return floor(math(0, 'random')*(max - min + 1) + min)px

multiple-box-shadow($n)
    $value = random(0, 2000) random(0, 2000) white
    for $i in (1...$n)
        $value = $value , random(0, 2000) random(0, 2000) white
    return $value
```